# For loop integer in table name

Tags: lua, insert, lua-table

I'm trying to insert into a table with the for loop integer in the end, how is it possible on lua?

My attempt on doing it

```
local table1 = {}
local table2 = {}
local table3 = {}

for i = 1, 3, 1 do
   table.insert("table" .. i, 1, "ok")
end
```

Comment: I found a way to do it, table.insert(_G["table" .. i], 1, "ok") how ever, I edited my question as I forgot to add "local" before the table names, and this does not work on local, so I still am looking for a way to do it with local table names

Answer (score 0):

Put the tables into another table.

```
local tables = {{}, {}, {}}

for i = 1, 3, 1 do
  table.insert(tables[i], 1, "ok")
end
```

Comment: I'm not interested in doing that, I would like to know how to do it with table1,2 etc

Comment: That's not possible with local variables. When you find yourself wanting to get variable names algorithmicly, you don't want a mechanism that can access any variable in your program. You should always put such data into a larger table (which may have string keys, if you prefer).

Comment: What do you mean with access any variable in my program? AFAIK it can only locally receive information from it

Comment: When variable names are set in stone by declarations rather than made from strings, it's much easier for the interpreter to help you find mistakes and prevent bugs. If you tell us what problem you're trying to solve with this, we might be able to give you a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is getting a table by key with index.So you can construct a table like(as your _G["table" .. i]):

```
local t = {
    ["table" .. 1] = {};    
    ["table" .. 2] = {};
    -- ...
}
```

if you don't construct local table, you must get the local table name. You can try _ENV(5.3) or getenvf(5.1) to get it, but i guess it may be not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the debug library to spelunk through the locals in your function, but I can't recommend that.

Otherwise, there is no list of locals unless you make one:

```
local table1 = {}
local table2 = {}
local table3 = {}

local tables = { table1 = table1, table2 = table2, table3 = table3 }

for i = 1, 3, 1 do
   table.insert(tables["table" .. i], 1, "ok")
end
```